# UIView Animation version issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting this error:

> beginAnimations:context: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 -
>   Use the block-based animation API instead for these lines.

I am trying to learn Swift coding and doing some work with carousels. Can someone please help me to change these lines to be swift 5 compatible.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:itemView.superview];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
[self performSelector:@selector(queueItemView:) withObject:itemView afterDelay:0.1];
itemView.superview.layer.opacity = 0.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:0.1];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:INSERT_DURATION];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(depthSortViews)];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:INSERT_DURATION];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(didScroll)];
[self transformItemViews];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Ummm that doesn't look like swift code. That looks more OBJ-C style.

Answer (score 3):

Don't confuse Swift (the language) with iOS / Cocoa (the framework). This has nothing to do with Swift 5 or any other Swift. Your problem here is that in iOS 13, Cocoa itself doesn't like the call you are making.

Instead of the (very) old `beginAnimations` / `commitAnimations` syntax, you should use either [`UIView.animate(withDuration:...)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate) or a [UIViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewpropertyanimator).

Answer (score 0):

CALayer animations are pretty old now. For learning more Swifty-way of working with animations, I recommend you to read [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5304228-ios-animation-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial. But if you are in need of code translation then you can try to use [Swiftify](https://objectivec2swift.com/#/home) as a tool for basic code conversion from Objective-C to Swift. You will get the following result:

```
//  Converted to Swift 5.1 by Swiftify v5.1.33915 - https://objectivec2swift.com/
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.1)
UIView.setAnimationDelegate(itemView.superview)
UIView.setAnimationDidStop(#selector(UIView.removeFromSuperview))
perform(#selector(queueItemView(_:)), with: itemView, afterDelay: 0.1)
itemView.superview.layer.opacity = 0.0
UIView.commitAnimations()

UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
UIView.setAnimationDelay(0.1)
UIView.setAnimationDuration(INSERT_DURATION)
UIView.setAnimationDelegate(self)
UIView.setAnimationDidStop(#selector(depthSortViews))
UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
UIView.setAnimationDuration(INSERT_DURATION)
UIView.setAnimationDelegate(self)
UIView.setAnimationDidStop(#selector(didScroll))
transformItemViews()
UIView.commitAnimations()
```

You will probably may need to correct it a bit.